# Is it possible to have a platform-specific plugin in a Cordova 7 app?

Tags: cordova, configuration, cordova-plugins

I have been unable to find any documentation on how to make a plugin specific to a certain platform (e.g. Android) using Cordova 7. It seems that putting the `<plugin>` element in the `config.xml` file is not valid. Is there any (good) way to achieve this?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no provision to add plugin specific to platform. Also I don't see a need for this. If the plugin is not supported in iOS for example, then automatically it will not be included in the build as far as I have observed. Your thoughts?

Comment: @Gandhi Unfortunately, if I include an Android-only plugin on another platform, while it won't produce any errors (since the Android only build material won't be included), it will copy over the js-module (i.e. `www/plugin.js`) from the plugin to the app.

Comment: Not possible. As a possible workaround you use a cordova `hook` to remove plugin from the specific platform you want to exclude.

Comment: @johnborges What files would I need to remove/edit to accomplish that? I'll accept that as an answer if you'd care to post. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use plugman : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/plugman.html

From the plugman documentation :

- If you use a **cross-platform** workflow, you use the cordova CLI utility to add plugins, as described in The Command-Line Interface. The CLI modifies plugins for all specified platforms at once.
- If you use a **platform-centered** workflow, you use a lower-level Plugman command-line interface, separately for each targeted platform.

Comment: and be careful before use: `Before you can use Plugman, you must create a Cordova project.` as cordova 8.0.0